# Xamarin XfxComboBox Show suggestion items on focus

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

So I have implemented XfxComboBox (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xfx.Controls/) and I want to display all suggested items when I focus entry, but without typing anything? Is that possible?

Comment: Hi YeetYeet, welcome to the community! This post is a bit light on details and could use some description of how your Combo Box is implemented and what you have already tried. Please edit this post and you will be far more likely to get a useful response.

Comment: Could you provide the code and the screenshot with what you want?